# Problema al decodificar imagen de la dirección URL: Internet Explorer con PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema al mostrar una imagen en Internet Explorer, me da este error en consola "No se pudo descodificar la imagen en la dirección: 
 `URL: 'file://10.133.83.23/mdc/imagenes/00800029.002.jpg'`. La imagen esta en un host local y no se muestra, probé con otras imágenes y si se muestran, desconozco si las imágenes del host local vengan codificadas, he visto que tal vez vengan en base64, estoy utilizando `xampp` para correr la app, son todas formato `.jpg` y estoy usando este código.

```
<?php
    $filename = '00800029.002'.'.jpg';
    $path = '//10.133.82.134/pegaso/IMAGENES/';
    if( file_exists($path . $filename) ) {
         echo "file:$path$filename";
         echo "<img src='file:$path$filename' width='100' height='50'>";
    } else {
         echo 'No existe el fichero';
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que pese a ser un host local, si la ruta especificada para `file://` no es una ruta de tu sistema de archivos, lo que realmente se hace es una petición http, por ende debería ser:

```
echo "<img src='http:$path$filename' width='100' height='50'>";
```

Además, ten en cuenta que `file_exists()` solo sirve para archivos locales especificando una ruta, ya sea algo del estilo `/var/www/pegaso/IMAGENES` (o la localización del archivo) o una relativa al proyecto `pegaso/IMAGENES`.

Finalmente, te recomendaría utilizar comillas dobles para el HTML, es más, PHP no solo permite utilizar comillas simples, sino que lo más óptimo (y mejor práctica) es hacerlo. Podrías dejarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
echo '<img src="http:', $path, $filename, '" width="100" height="50">';
```

Además es importante destacar que a la hora de utilizar `echo`, lo más eficiente es separar por comas los strings que vaya a ir mostrando, pues por ejemplo si utilizaramos `.` para concatenar, sería más costoso.